# Manejo de estados en base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Seria correcto tener una tabla ESTADO  en my base de datos y que lo usen todas las tablas, para asi no tener que escribir el campo estado en cada una de ellas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la idea es optimizar recursos, caerías en lo mismo, o aún peor, ya que el estado regularmente hace referencia a cada uno de los registros de las otras tablas, entonces tendrías una tabla por ejemplo llamada estado, y otro campo que hace referencia a la tabla origen, así como al registro, sería una relación uno a muchos. en todo caso si colocas el campo estado en cada tabla, te ahorras mucho mas espacio y memoria.